# How to wait for a plist write operation to complete?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, plist

How can one wait for a plist write operation to complete before performing other operations?

```
// Write plist file
NSString *pathToPlist = [NSString pathWithComponents:@[[Util documentsDirectoryPath], @"Settings.plist"]];
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:pathToDocumentsPlist];
[dic setObject:@"SomeObject" @"SomeKey"];
[dic writeToFile:pathToDocumentsPlist atomically:YES];

// Read plist file
NSDictionary *updatedDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: pathToPlist];
```

In this case, I would like the `updatedDictionary` to have value of the updated plist, however the plist write method (`writeToFile`) seems to be asynchronous and takes an amount of time to complete. As a result, `updatedDictionary` tends to read in the old, instead of the updated configuration, since by the time of the plist read, the save operation was not completed.

How can one resolve this issue? Just a pure speculation, could setting `atomically:NO` possibly help? Thanks!

Comment: `writeToFile:atomically:` is synchronous and is finished when the method returns. The code you posted is reading from a different path than you write to.

Comment: Both `pathToPlist` and `pathToDocumentsPlist` seems to be pointing at a same path, although they are 2 `NSString` objects, can this matter though?

Comment: `pathToDocumentsPlist` was an earlier created `NSString`, `pathToPlist` is later created separately. If `writeToFile:atomically:` is synchronous, I'll try to find what went wrong myself. Thanks :)

Comment: You are sending message unknown "writeToFile" to NSMutableDictionary as the "writeToFile" method is only available in NSData. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 0):

First point this method is not asynchronous, it is synchronous, it returns a boolean when the operation succeeds or not, so you are probably not checking if it was saved, and probably this is your problem. Check the return of the writeToFile:atomically:!

Now, a really simple question, why you are doing this?

this is your code:

```
// Write plist file
NSString *pathToPlist = [NSString pathWithComponents:@[[Util documentsDirectoryPath], @"Settings.plist"]];
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:pathToDocumentsPlist];
[dic setObject:@"SomeObject" @"SomeKey"];
[dic writeToFile:pathToDocumentsPlist atomically:YES];

// Read plist file
NSDictionary *updatedDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: pathToPlist];
```

First you are reading the plist to a dictionary - OK

Second you are updating the data in the dictionary - OK

Third you are saving the dictionary to the plist again - OK

Fourth you are getting the plist again - WHY?

You already have the content of the plist in your dictionary, as you updated the plist using "dic", so why you need to read the same again if it will have exactly the same content of the plist?? dic and plist are the same at that point of your code.

if you want to make sure that the content was saved,the method writeToFile:atomically returns a boolean where you can see if the operation succeeds or not. By the way, if this method returns a boolean saying that the operation was complete, the method cannot be asynchronous, to be asynchronous it should use block not a return value.

About your question with the "atomically", no, it will not make it synchronous or asynchronous, describing it in the simplest way, this atomically means that "no one" can access the content of this file until it is completely saved, so it will save in some temporary place, when it is complete, it will move to the final destination, so if some object try to read/update/delete it before it is completely saved, it will not be possible.

at the end try this to write your plist:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

if([dic writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/Settings.plist"] atomically:YES])
//it worked
```

cheers,

Roberto

Comment: Thanks, I have resolved the problem. To answer the question, the reason that I used another `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile` to get the contents, is that the dictionary is also modified elsewhere (in another thread). Thanks for your answer anyway!